# Form_for not saving data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I for the life of me can't figure out what I am doing wrong with my code here.  I have a form_for, but when I click save, it doesn't save the data from the form, just the data in the controller.

Controller:

```
class RegistersController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

  def new
    @reg = Register.new
  end

  def create
    @reg = Register.new(params.permit(:user, :user_id, :class_id))
    @reg.user_id = current_user.id

    @reg.save
  end

  def update

  end
end
```

New:

```
<%= form_for @reg do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :class_name, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <%= f.text_area :class_name, class: "form-control"%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :user, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <%= f.text_area :user, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

Model:

```
class Register < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :event, optional: true
end
```

Edit:

I did some messing around further and got here:
@reg = Register.new(params.required(:user).permit(:user_id, :class_name))

This is giving me the log:

```
    Processing by RegistersController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"BJr3T+RiI0YiyixC6EORKtMG3L8Q9LP3kL7Dh4apt0WdeGzN5mVhy/oNn64+xF9TRRztLqL5/Hf6WEwhucRF8w==", "register"=>{"class_name"=>"Toddler", "user"=>"Billy"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
    Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
```

Comment: Where is the `current_user` method defined? However, some logs could make the situation much cleaner

Comment: Would you share logs with us?

Comment: You're wanting the text from the :user and :class_name text area to be saved to your Register model? :class_name is not being permitted in your controller, just :class_id. Is that another model?

Comment: current_user saves fine, that comes from devise.  I added the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like:

```rb
  def create
    @reg = Register.new(params.required(:register).permit(:user_id, :class_name))
    @reg.user_id = current_user.id
    @reg.save! # This will raise exception if something is wrong
  end
```

Btw, just apply to TDD/BDD concepts to eliminate problems like this one. This process is pretty simple.